# embedded youtube player with links that onclick play another video in same embedded player

Tags: html, youtube, embed, hyperlink

my problem is that everything works fine in FF but not for chrome/IE/safari. if anyone can help out it would be GREATLY appreciated!! PS: can't use iFrame.

here's the code: first part of code needs beginning script and end script since the script code won't show.

```
    <script>
     function play(clip){
       document.getElementById("frame").src= 
         "http://www.youtube.com/v/"+clip+"&autoplay=0&rel=0";
     } 
    </script>

    <object width="375" height="295">
       <param name="movie" value=""></param>
       <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
       <param name="border" value="0"></param>
       <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
       <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
       <embed id ="frame" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/CsGYh8AacgY?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" border="0" allowfullscreen=true allowscriptaccess = always wmode="transparent" width="375" height="295"></embed>
    </object><br />

    <B>Choose Video:</B>
    <a href="#" onclick="play('CsGYh8AacgY'); return false" style="color:#9b9898; font-size:12">Charlie 1</a> | 
    <a href="#" onclick="play('QFCSXr6qnv4'); return false" style="color:#9b9898; font-size:12">Charlie 2</a> | 
    <a href="#" onclick="play('eaCCkfjPm0o'); return false" style="color:#9b9898; font-size:12">Charlie 3</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the movie param is not being set. However, I am not sure if setting that directly will cause the movie to reload. If you are not opposed to using some javascript libraries, this is what I would do:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function play(clip){
       var mv = "http://www.youtube.com/v/"+clip+"&autoplay=0&rel=0";
       swfobject.embedSWF(mv, "myContent", "375", "295", "8");
     }
     $(document).ready(function() {
       play('CsGYh8AacgY');
     });
    </script>

    <div id="myContent"></div>
    <br />

    <B>Choose Video:</B>
    <a href="#" onclick="play('CsGYh8AacgY'); return false" style="color:#9b9898; font-size:12">Charlie 1</a> |
    <a href="#" onclick="play('QFCSXr6qnv4'); return false" style="color:#9b9898; font-size:12">Charlie 2</a> |
    <a href="#" onclick="play('eaCCkfjPm0o'); return false" style="color:#9b9898; font-size:12">Charlie 3</a>
```

This uses the SWFObject and JQuery libraries. SWFObject is what handles loading the flash movie. JQuery is not strictly necessary here, I am just using it to load a default video when the page has loaded completely `$(document).ready`. I point to the google hosted libraries, but you can download them and serve them locally if you would prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Trythis,

```
 $('a.video').click(function () {
     var id = $(this).attr('data-youtube');
     var src = '//www.youtube.com/embed/'+id;
     var iframe = '<iframe id="youtube" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" src="'+src+'" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
     $(".video-wrapper").html(iframe);
     return false;
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rakesh_vadnal/pyktnz7r/2/